# Coding core application in Visual Studio C++ but GUI in Delphi?

Tags: c++, delphi

I'd like to have a nice/modern Windows GUI which can be easily done. I have used Delphi in the past and it was a breeze to create a "nice" GUI.

I have created the core of my application in C++ (with VS2015) but I don't know about MFC, Qt,... to create a GUI. Is it recommended to just put my core application into a DLL and the Delphi GUI calls my DLL?

I would also like to have (database) SQL functionality (with possibility of local and remote database) which can be easily implemented with specific Delphi components. So, Delphi here is a good approach too.

Any other suggestion than splitting my project into a (C++) DLL and a (Delphi) EXE/GUI?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure your answer is no. However, you could consider using Embarcadero C++ Builder. It uses the exact same framework(s) and libraries that Delphi uses, and it's in a familiar C++ language.

Comment: I think this only works if the interface between visual C++ and Delphi is very narrow and can be wrapped easily in plain C. I do this regularly (with VS community edition) to access SDKs for VC++ from Delphi

Comment: If you are going to create a DLL, give it a C (POD) interface, or, alternatively, a COM interface. Most languages, including Delphi and even other C++ implementations, can't consume C++ DLLs directly. More (including an example) here: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html